# Asterisk: Can call but can't hear voice

Tags: fedora, asterisk, voip

I set up a simple asterisk server on Fedora. My goal is to make two android phones call each other. Actually they are connected via wifi, and I use Zoiper and Jitsi softphone. Fedora is on a virtualbox machine with bridged network mode (ip: 192.168.1.13)

> sip.conf:

```
[general]
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
svrlookup=no
autokill=yes

[myTemplate](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=myLocalPhones
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm

[5001](myTemplate)
secret=5001
mailbox=5001@default

[5002](myTemplate)
secret=5002
mailbox=5002@default
```

> extensions.conf:

```
[myLocalPhones]

exten => 222,1,Dial(SIP/5001)

exten => 123,1,Answer()
exten => 123,2,Playback(hello-world)
exten => 123,3,Hangup()
```

I can make a call and answer but there is no voice ! neither the hello-world message!

Comment: Firewalls? Is there NAT anywhere in the circuit? Can each device ping the others?

Comment: Hi @roaima there is no firewalls neither NAT, I can make a call but there is no voice !

Answer (score 0):

¿Are the Android phones in the same network?

Try to use this config in the "myTemplate" template.

```
nat=force_rport,comedia
```